# htaccess and authentication for multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess, typo3

I am running a mutlisite TYPO3-Site.

For the pre-live process, I want to add a `htaccess` with a `htpasswd` for 3 / 4 sites.

How can I configure the htaccess-file to trigger the authentication only for specific urls?

For example:

http://example.org shouldn't get a password-protection,
while http://example2.org should.

Both sites are on the same server and handled by the CMS.

Since the usual htaccess-stuff looks like this:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/my/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Geschützter Bereich"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET>
    require valid-user
</Limit>
```

It would trigger for every site.

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make it so authorisation unless the host ends in example2.com

```
# set the "require_auth" var if Host ends with "example2.com"
SetEnvIfNoCase Host example2\.com$ require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
#except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```